# How to search for embedded files during runtime C#

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

Is it possible to search for embedded files that match a specific search criteria (e.g. *.xml).

My Code at the moment (works just for files i know the Path to)

```
var fileName = "PATH.sample.xml";
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fileName);

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var findedResourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
     .Where(name => name.EndsWith(".xml")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("yourPath", "*.xml");

foreach (string file in files)
{
   //do what you need here
}
```